# Adobe Cirrus in Flash app without Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, adobe-cirrus

Now I am using Adobe Cirrus in my Flex app, but I think that Flex is too complicated for such simple application.

Is it possible to use Adobe Cirrus in plain Flash apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , it is possible.

[flash.net](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package-detail.html) package classes,which are working with `Cirrus`, are native `Actionscript3.0` classes, not part of `Flex SDK`.